# Is XPATH supported in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath, cross-browser

Please check the below code, it's working fine in Firefox but not working in internet explorer.

Can any one please help me on this?

HTML file: (finaltest.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var items= new Array();
            var details = new Array();
            var contents = new Array();

            function allCall()
            {
                readXMLUsingXPATH();
                populateList();
            }
            function populateList()
            {
                for(var list=0; list<items.length; list++){
                    var temp= new Option(items[list],items[list]);
                    document.getElementById('sel').options.add(temp);
                    //alert("in populatelist");
                }
            }

            function addContent(divName, content) 
            {
                //alert(content);
                document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
            }

            function loadXML(){
                var xmlhttp;
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Micrsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","details.xml",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseXML;
            }

            function readXMLUsingXPATH(){
                var xmlDoc = loadXML();
                if(xmlDoc == null){
                    alert("XML HTTP object is null");
                    return;
                }
                var path1 = "/Root/Item/name";
                var path2 = "/Root/Item/details";
                var path3 =  "/Root/Item/content";
                var xmlNoadList1,xmlNoadList2,xmlNoadList3,result1,result2,result3,name,detail,content,list;
                if(window.ActiveXObject){
                    xmlNoadList1 = xmlDoc.selectNodes(path1);
                    xmlNoadList2 = xmlDoc.selectNodes(path2);
                    xmlNoadList3 = xmlDoc.selectNodes(path3);
                    for(list=0; list<xmlNoadList1.length; list++){
                        items[list]=xmlNoadList1[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        name = xmlNoadList1[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                    for(list=0; list<xmlNoadList2.length; list++){
                        details[list]=xmlNoadList2[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        detail = xmlNoadList2[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }
                    for(list=0; list<xmlNoadList3.length; list++){
                        contents[list]=xmlNoadList3[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        content = xmlNoadList3[list].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    }

                }
                else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){
                    xmlNoadList1 = xmlDoc.evaluate(path1, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                    xmlNoadList2 = xmlDoc.evaluate(path2, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                    xmlNoadList3 = xmlDoc.evaluate(path3, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                    result1 = xmlNoadList1.iterateNext();
                    result2 = xmlNoadList2.iterateNext();
                    result3 = xmlNoadList3.iterateNext();
                    list=0;
                    while(result1){
                        name = result1.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        items[list]=result1.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        result1 = xmlNoadList1.iterateNext();
                        list++;
                    }
                    list=0;
                    while(result2){
                        detail = result2.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        details[list]=result2.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        result2 = xmlNoadList2.iterateNext();
                        list++;
                    }
                    list=0;
                    while(result3){
                        content = result3.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        contents[list]=result3.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        result3 = xmlNoadList3.iterateNext();
                        list++;
                    }
                }
            //alert("in xml");
            }
            function itemDetails(name,ind){
                //alert(details[ind]);
                document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = details[ind] + "</br>" + contents[ind];
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body >

        <form name="myForm">
            Content to be added:
            <SELECT name="sel" id="sel" size="4" onChange="addContent('result', this[this.selectedIndex].text);">
            </SELECT>
            <input type="button" value="Details" onClick="itemDetails('result', document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex)">
        </form>
        <br><br>
        Your content will be added dynamically below:
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        onload=allCall;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

XML file: (details.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Item>
        <name>Item1</name>
        <details>Item1 Details</details>
        <content>Item1 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item2</name>
        <details>Item2 Details</details>
        <content>Item2 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item3</name>
        <details>Item3 Details</details>
        <content>Item3 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item4</name>
        <details>Item4 Details</details>
        <content>Item4 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item5</name>
        <details>Item5 Details</details>
        <content>Item5 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item6</name>
        <details>Item6 Details</details>
        <content>Item6 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item7</name>
        <details>Item7 Details</details>
        <content>Item7 Content</content>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>Item8</name>
        <details>Item8 Details</details>
        <content>Item8 Content</content>
    </Item>
</Root>
```

Comment: TL;DR. Come up with the smallest possible code that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said what exactly happens when you run your code sample with IE, which version of IE you tried, which error you get for which statement. One possible issue is simply a typo in your code, instead of `xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Micrsoft.XMLHTTP")` you need `xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`. Whether that is the part of your code causing your problem is hard to tell, it depends on the IE version and its settings whether that code branch is used at all.

Comment: It gives error at "xmlhttp.open("GET","details.xml",false);" as Access is denied and I am using IE9 beta.

Comment: Well using a beta version of a browser that has long been released makes it hard for most people to reproduce problems as most will use the final release of IE 9 these days and not a beta. And we need to know more details anyway, do you load the HTML document with the script over HTTP from a HTTP server or directly from the file system? Did you debug your code, when you get the error, have you checked whether the XMLHttpRequest branch has been used or the new ActiveXObject branch?

Comment: Yes I debug the code. I think error is because of XMLHttpRequest branch. It gives me error as "Access is Denied" at "xmlhttp.open("GET","details.xml",false);".

Comment: Are you sure it is a relative URL like "details.xml" that is giving you an access is denied? I uploaded your code samples to http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2011/07/test2011071801.html and it works fine with IE 9 (final release of course, don't have any beta any more around).

Comment: But It's not working fine in my local machine in Internet Explorer.It's working fine in Firefox.Can you please provide me any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it does not work for you. The first suggestion obviously is do install the final IE 9 version instead of using a beta. Then try the posted case again. We could also ask other readers here to test whether anyone else runs into the 'access is denied" error you say you get, then we would need to compare the settings of the different IE installations. But all that is not related to XPath at all it seems, rather to IE installation and configuration problems when it comes to XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

According to a blog post at

- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/04/xpath-in-javascript-part-3/

Internet Explorer (at least up to IE8) doesnt implement the [DOM Level 3 XPath Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/) on `document` but provides it's own implementation via the [MSXML2.DOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ActiveX object on XML documents.

Comment: I already used MSXML2.DOMDocument object but still it's not working in internet explorer.can u please give me one example which working fine in internet explorer?

Comment: @Priyanka the article I linked above has examples

Answer (score -1):

A pitfall in IE 9 is that it supports some methods that previously have been associated with other browsers.  For example I have a code that was working in IE 8 and Firefox, but not in IE 9. The explanation was very simple:  IE 9 was attempting to run down the Firefox branch, and failing of course: IE9 does not support document.evaluate method of Xpath.

```
    // Code for Firefox
    // Wrong!
    if ( document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument ) {  
    // stops IE8, but not IE9 from running the below code
    // do some Xpath stuff ie. document.evaluate(//more code here )}

    // Correct
    if ( navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ) {  

    // stops IE 8 and IE 9 from running the below code
    // do some Xpath stuff  ie. document.evaluate(//more code here )   }
```

Comment: I recommend against this. Feature detection is always going to be more robust than browser-name blacklisting. The problem was not that you were doing feature detection, but that you were doing it wrong; if it's `document.evaluate` that you're using, you should test for `document.evaluate` (rather than `document.dimplementation.createDocument`).